# MySQL changing large table to InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a MySQL server running on CentOS which houses a large (>12GB) DB. I have been advised to move to InnoDB for performance reasons as we are experiencing lockups where the application that relies on the DB becomes unresponsive when the server is busy.

I have been reading around and can see that the ALTER command that changes the table to InnoDB is likely to take a long time and hammer the server in the process.  As far as I can see, the only change required is to use the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE t ENGINE=InnoDB
```

I have run this on a test server and it seems to complete fine, taking about 26 minutes on the largest of the tables that needs to be converted.

Having never run this on a production system I am interested to know the following:

1. What changes are recommended to be made to the MySQL config to take advantage of additional performance of InnoDB tables? The server currently has 3GB assigned to InnoDB cache - was thinking of increasing this to 15GB once the additional RAM is installed.
2. Is there anything else I should do to the server with this change?

Comment: Do you mean [InnoDB buffer pool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html)? Also, save yourself some future headache and use [file per table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-multiple-tablespaces.html).

Comment: `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is definitely what will govern the performance. An SSD as well, if you don't have one (RAID etc.). File per table might help, but will introduce huge issues on servers with high concurrency so I wouldn't change that one just yet. Alternatively, for performance - check out [TokuDB](http://www.tokutek.com/tokudb-for-mysql/) which is also a drop-in replacement that boasts with even more performance.

Comment: @MarcusAdams yes I did mean the InnoDB buffer pool, thanks. I am migrating to a new server with SSD cache but at the moment need to keep the old one running a bit longer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would really recommend using either Percona MySQL or MariaDB. Both have tools that will help you get the most out of InnoDB, as well as some tools to help you diagnose and optimize your database further (for example, Percona's Online Schema Change tool could be used to alter your tables without downtime).

As far as optimization of InnoDB, I think most would agree that innodb_buffer_pool_size is one of the most important parameters to tune (and typically people set it around 70-80% of total available memory, but that's not a magic number). It's not the only important config variable, though, and there's really no magic run_really_fast setting. You should also pay attention to innodb_buffer_pool_instances (and there's a good discussion about this topic on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194/how-do-you-tune-mysql-for-a-heavy-innodb-workload)

Also, you should definitely check out the tips offered in the MySQL documentation itself (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimizing-innodb.html). It's also a good idea to pay attention to your InnoDB hit ratio (Rolado over at DBA Stackexchange has a great answer on this topic, eg, https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65341/innodb-buffer-pool-hit-rate) and analyze your slow query logs carefully. Towards that later end, I would definitely recommend taking a look at Percona again. Their slow query analyzer is top notch and can really give you a leg up when it comes to optimizing SQL performance.